# Android Material Design vs ContentObserver

Tags: android, material-design, contentobserver, shared-element-transition

I will try to explain my question as best.

Along my search on where to register / unregister my ContentObserver I see multiple answer saying that it should be at onResume / onPause or onStart / onStop but not in onCreate / onDestroy.
Let say I had the register / un register in onStart / onStop, to be sure that my view is still updated with fresh data, I fetch the data then refresh my view in the onStart method before registering the ContentObserver.

It's all OK and works fine untill... SharedElement with Material Design transition.

Because Imagine
Activity A register to Data-A and in onStart refresh the data so the View.
When user touch an item, it run a SharedElement animation to the detail of this Item: Activity B with Data-A[n]

The problem is when I get back to Activity A from Activity B, the origin item in my list no longer exist because of the refresh of my Data, and my animation have not the desire behaviour.

Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

If the original data gets replaced then you should not use shared element transition itself. Rather you could take snapshots and attach to the overlay of the destination activities to achieve the desired animation.

Take a look at the [Shared element callbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SharedElementCallback.html).

Basically on shared element start you take the snapshot, add it to the window overlay, animate it and then hide it if you need it. So when you get back if you dont have your data just simulate something like that using snapshots again or just skip the animations altogether.

Take a look at the [following link](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/reveal-activity-transitions/), it demonstrates the same thing.

Comment: Thanks i would take à look, i was thinking of using ShareElementCallback. To be more specific my data don't change all the time, i jut refresh the view at onStart to be sure to not miss a change. Just an idea but what about refresh the view after the animation is finished ?

Comment: it all depends on your use case. The idea of snapshot is animating something when there are no common elements (by the look at least) between the two activities.